# Отправка данных с сервера клиенту. WebSocket. WS module

Tags: javascript, websocket

Код был полностью взят с [источника](https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80).

Все работает прекрасно. Но не могу реализовать отправку переменной к клиенту при коннекте.

Есть переменная `timer`, допустим она равна единице. Мне нужно при коннекте юзеря передать ему эту единицу с сервера. Пробовал заменить переменную `message` на свою - ошибка. Пробовал вынести `ws.send(timer)` в тело `webSocketServer.on('connection', function(ws) {` - Ошибка. Но просто строка типа `"1"` - идет удачно. Т.е. не передается именно переменная. Есть ли решение ?

Comment: Быть может, существуют проблемы с передачей `Number` (передаётся в бинарном виде или ещё как-то). Можно попробовать так: `ws.send(timer + "")`.

Comment: @Regent Сделайте ответ на этот вопрос. Я приму его как верный. Вы были правы, дело в numver. строку без вопросов передало. Спасибо !

Comment: На здоровье. Сейчас оформлю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [документации MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#send()) говорится про передачу `String` - про передачу `Number` ничего не сказано. Возможно, числа передаются в бинарном виде.

Можно привести число к строке и передать строку. Например, так: `ws.send(timer + "")`.